# Get value from element <a> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to get text from element . I am beginner. I was trying this solution, but result was:

```
<a href="#" id="text">Hello</a>
```

I know why, but I dont know how to get only text Hello. Can you help me please?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="text">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp), like so

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="text">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

---

`.innerHTML` will return the HTML code and `.textContext` should return the actual text.

---

**.innerHTML**

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;//Returns "<b>Hello</b>"
```

```
<a href="#" id="text"><b>Hello</b></a>
```

---

**.textContent**

```
document.getElementById('text').textContext;//Returns "Hello"
```

```
<a href="#" id="text"><b>Hello</b></a>
```

---

`.textContent` is better overall for getting the *actual* text of an element.

---

**Note that** [`.innerText`] also works like .textContent but is more aware of what to return.

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)